# terminal will not load, cant run any commands just blinks can't type

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

terminal will not load and "if" it does it never loads a prompt ex: username:machinename#, only the windows frame, file menu and a blinking cursor, cant type anything, cant run commands, have no idea how to fix this without being able to run any commands, all "how-tos" start with run this command ;) cant anyone help, I'm afraid I'm going to have to blow out my system due to this. running ubuntu 18.04.2

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you purged or removed some package recently? Go to TTY mode using Ctrl+Alt+Fx (where Fx can vary from F1-F7) and try to reinstall gnome-terminal using `sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-terminal`.

Comment: I would love to purge or reinstall but can't terminal is dead, and synaptic-package manger wont open, i'm going no where

Comment: I tried to boot in recovery mode and ran the dkpg repair but no help

Comment: Do you mean you can't open TTY mode as well?

Comment: correct, TTY does nothing i can press those keys all i want

Comment: synaptic wont open and the software center only allows me to LAUNCH no install, remove, etc...

Comment: Do you have SSH, VNC running? I think you'll need to use a live USB to boot, mount your root drive, chroot, then launch aptitude/apt from the USB.

Comment: At the login screen, enter your username, then notice the cogwheel icon, click on it to select your environment, and it should probably be set to `Ubuntu` or `Ubuntu on Xorg`. Report back.

Comment: Some background also might be helpful. Is this a machine you've been using for a long time? Or a brand new install? Were you performing an update when this broke? Did it ever work? What were you doing when it broke? Etc.

Comment: this is not a new install, ran updates and kernel was updated yesterday, worked fine on two days ago when I was last using it. maybe the updates did break it, i noticed today when i went to open to ssh to server and it would load, that is when my day started to take a turn for the worst. I feel helpless never seen this before.

Comment: added screenshot just a blinking cursor, never loads the normal username:systemname# before the cursor, so you cant type just click on menu items

Comment: VNC is not running, and i see SSH-AGENT in the processes

Comment: yes my session logs in to Ubuntu

Comment: check your .bashrc file.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer...

From the comments...

User is having problem with various applications not running correctly.

We created a new, temporary "guest" account, logged in there, and the applications are working there. There's something wrong in the original user's account.

We've eliminated the .local and .config folders as suspect. We're doing more testing now...

Comment: i just tried this, but same issue, i'm  using gmone 3, all default ubuntu 18.04.2 options I stopped tweaking my workstation years ago. the system logs in automatically.

Comment: @dEadRaVens create a temporary "guest" account, login there, and see if you have the same problem(s). Report back.

Comment: ok it freezes on black screen if i "switched user" but it did log in if I "logged out" to a new user, and terminal opens fine and works ;) should i try uninstalling it here now, or does this prove that terminal is fine, and something is wrong with the other user profile?

Comment: It means there's something wrong in your original user home folder... probably something in .local or .config. Using the FILES application, rename .local to .local.HOLD. Log out. Log in. Retry terminal. If it works, something is wrong in the .local.HOLD folder. Do the same for the .config folder. But only do one folder at a time. Report back.

Comment: .local didnt have any effect, .config changed everything "desktop wise" but terminal still no go on either change, now it doesnt open at all not even a dummy window. I only changed one folder at a time with logging out and in between each change, and change the .local folder back to original before changing the .config folder, hope that was right.

Comment: Well, no... I didn't tell you to rename anything back, yet. .local and .config will get recreated when the system can't find them, so there's a specific way you have to restore the original folders. Does `gedit` open to a normal window, or a transparent window?

Comment: OK renamed .local back to .local.HOLD and .config.HOLD remains renamed, and gedit opens a normal window (white background)

Comment: Later, when you log out and log in, you'll see fresh .local and .config folders. What you'll end up doing is to move the new .local and .config folders to the desktop, rename the .HOLD folders back to their original names, and then IMMEDIATELY log out and log in, and then delete the two folders on the desktop. For further troubleshooting... and this will take some time... is create a folder on the Desktop called temp.HOLD... then move a bunch of stuff from your current home folder (except the major folders like Documents/Music/Pictures/Etc.) to the temp.HOLD folder. Log out. Log in. Retest...

Comment: Retest terminal. Until you find what's causing the problem. Report back.

Comment: Im lost, and i feel horrible bothering you! i moved all hidden folders from /home into /desktop/temp.HOLD and still no go, at this point im thinking trying to reinstall or re-configuring the new user profile is the only way to go it is clear that this profile is the problem, i spent the whole day just trying to open a terminal, this machine has never been a problem until today, so much for rock solid. i was hit with the unlucky stick today! can you think of anything else i can try?

Comment: **I know it's frustrating, but you're on the right path, it's just going to take a little while longer.** If you've moved all the hidden folders, now try moving the other individual files (but not the Document/Music/Pictures/Etc. folders). And yes, we proved that the guest account worked fine, and your account doesn't, so we're close. I put together a quick skeleton answer, that I'll modify and complete later. Keep trying! Report back when you can.

Comment: sorry i lost it, cried like a baby... i moved everything i can, only things left are the files and folders that come right back upon log out/in... and still no go. nothing left to move??? i attched another screen shot

Comment: OK, step away from the computer. Make yourself a nice cup of decaf tea. Forget about it for a while. Come back to this later. You've done a good job so far. Just move the Cortex and Shares folder out, and delete the smb.conf file (sudo rm -i smb.conf). Retest. Report back later, ok?

Comment: lol herbal tea is all i drink no drinking smoking or caffeine or red meat yet in 2019! no dairy in over 13 years, and proud! lol
the Shares folder is a empty folder designed to mount Cortex, cortex is an internal HD that is mounted to Cortex, I guess i could unplug the drive but i have no where to move all that data, it isnt going onto my desktop, the main system HD is a SSD128GB disk... I have painted myself into a corner.

Comment: External disk mount points should be in /media, not your home folder. Anyway, lets confirm where we are... log into guest account and all apps work ok, yes? Log back into your account and the same apps still fail, yes?

Comment: same thing only terminal failes to load, I figured I would just move all my app data to new/guest profile but it wasn't that easy, all data is created with this account user1 so moving all my app/data to the new profile turned into a nightmare, wasnt as easy as i hoped it is a permission nightmare which is all over my head, im just a graphic/web designer, i only use terminal to ssh to my co-located server, and basic troubleshooting. wish i could just install another one but doesnt seem to be the case. i see this "move this discussion to chat" could we do that?

Comment: i stand corrected the /home folder is an additional internal disk, and / is the SSD, so i was able to move ALL the files out of home, still no deal, terminal still failed, so with a clean home folder i retried renaming the .config and .local folders from the beginning of this thread, but still does not work. i had to put all the data back so i could open thunderbird my email is blowing my phone up, moving all those folders and files is a instant copy paste, very fast, so i'm right back to where I was.

Comment: I'm going to see if maybe I can use the other profile to help this profile considering it does work there, if i go no where, maybe its time to do a reinstall, I have gotten lucky this machine, it has rocked for years, i REALLY appreciate your  time, and wish I could buy you a beer for all your time, im done for the night i need rest, thanks a million again! you're a kind soul, we need more of you in this world

Comment: @dEadRaVens although a beer sounds good, how about you just let me know how it goes after the reinstall. Then I can also update my answer. Cheers friend!

Comment: @dEadRaVens status please...

Comment: no status been livbing with it, i use my laptop to ssh. havent had any time to even think about it, so when i do have time ill do a fresh install just not looking forwqrd to that way to much to re-setup so i'm just glad the system is running, knock on wood! you can make this case solved ;) thanks for all your help.

Comment: @dEadRaVens thanks for the update! Yeah, a reinstall can be a drag, but if it ultimately fixes the problem, it's worth the effort. I can't mark this as solved... only you can... by clicking on the grey checkmark just to the left of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and then run the following commands:

```
cp ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc.bak
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/
source ~/.bashrc
```

If the terminal is not working with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, try to change the content of `~/.bashrc` manually.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to uncheck "Run a custom command instead of my shell" in the Edit -> Preference -> Command tab. See the image below.

[image]