# Terminal launches to a blinking cursor

Tags: command-line, tty

After a package installation using apt, all terminals stop working. To be more specific, I was getting a message every time I opened any terminal on my system:

```
Command 'ng' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install ng-common
```

After installing [this package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/ng-common) the terminal stopped responding. Instead of cursor and directory path now only a flashing prompt appears and I can't type anything. The image speaks for itself.

[image: Terminal with no directory path and with flashing prompt]

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 and Gnome 42.2. I already tried to uninstall some packages via package manager, but the problem persists. I uninstalled the terminal that came with the system, I also uninstalled another terminal emulator called Terminator. After restarting the system and reinstalling them, the problem continued. Even when I open the tty <kbd>CTRL + F3</kbd> I can't type anything in the terminal and the symptom is the same.

Has anyone gone through a similar situation? Is there any solution that can be run via GUI? Will I have to reinstall the system because of this?

Comment: what did you install with apt?

Comment: Please be more specific about both the actions leading up to the problem as well as all of the actions you've taken to try to resolve the problem.  Telling us that you've installed and then removed "packages" is ambiguous. Please edit your question and make sure your details are specific, clear, and unambiguous.

Comment: someone [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1131275/terminal-will-not-load-cant-run-any-commands-just-blinks-cant-type?rq=1) appears to have had the same issue, but no conclusive answer

Comment: ttys are handeled by the graphics card driver so if you use apt to install another one install the previous one you used.

Comment: if you can't do any installing in order to undo what you did, you can boot to a live USB, chroot into the install and run `apt install` from there

Comment: I added more details to the question.

Comment: 1) Check your .bashrc file. 2) Check whether it happens on another account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went through the same thing,

[ SHORT ANSWER ]

1. Use @Euclides Paim solution to uninstall the faulty package, you have to reboot if you dont see that package as installed.
2. Mark ng-common for complete removal [Hopefully this solves your problem of blinking cursor at terminal. If it doesn't, read the complete story below.]
3. To get rid of the initial problem use @T S solution.

[ Long Answer ]

1. first you need to install "Synaptic Package Manager" and then do as @Euclides Paim mentioned and then you search for ng-common in my case I couldn't find any installed packages before restarting my PC so you may wanna reboot.
2. I marked the ng-common for complete removal and then half way through removal my OS decided to uninstall my GUI and then threw me to a black screen and a blinking cursor on it, just like our terminal.
3. I tried rebooting I was always landed to the same black screen and blinking cursor, so I rebooted once more, On Grub I chose advanced option and selected dpkg to fix all the broken packages, it fixed my OS and now I had to reinstall my GUI, first I login at the black screen ( default landing screen when you have no GUI installed )
4. [sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop] and then the GUI was fixed. Now to solve the problem we all started.
5. use @T S , solution to fix the actual initial problem.

Answer (score 1):

probably, you had a line like the folling in your ~/.bashrc file:

```
# Load Angular CLI autocompletion.
source <(ng completion script)
```

you can comment that out, and your terminal will no longer hang on starting up.

Comment: I also had that line as the last in my `.bashrc` file. Strange though that the last modification of the file itself was about two months ago and the error only occurred today. I also didn't change anything in terms of Angular recently.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem by uninstalling the previously mentioned "ng-common" package, through [Synaptic Package Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzKxV.png). I still need to resolve the original [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDdoA.png) that got me into the problem , but at least now I have the terminal working again.

Thank you for everyone's collaboration.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I tried to install angular and broke my Terminal. I removed ng-common package through Synaptic Package Manager and it solved it as mentioned above. I get the same error lile Eclides Paim but terminal works !

Answer (score 0):

What i did was:

`ctrl+alt+F3` to enter tty3.
Logged in and pressed `ctrl+c` to be able to enter commands.
Entered command `sudo apt remove --purge ng-common`
pressed `ctrl+alt+F1` to exit tty3
It worked.
I still got "ng" not found error so i uninstalled @angular/cli